# SQL Server 2005 installation error 'cannot copy to encrypted or compressed folder'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

While installing SQL Server 2005 Express edition, I get this error:

> SQL server setup cannot install files to the encrypted or compressed folder : e:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server.

And suggests to ensure that directories are not encrypted or compressed. But I am able to use this drive normally for all other operation. My Windows version is XP Service Pack.

Any help or suggestions?

Comment: the error is not stating that you are unable to use the folder but that the folder is compressed or encrypted. did you check if the folders are compressed and/or encrypted?

Comment: Just **read** the error message! You're trying to install SQL Server 2005 onto a **compressed** or **encrypted** drive - and that is **NOT** supported! So install it somewhere else, onto a drive that is neither compressed, nor encrypted....

Comment: Tried installing in 'C' drive also failed for same reasons. Now I understand this drive can not be compressed or encryped.

Comment: Did the installation to the `C:` drive fails with the exact same error??

Comment: Yes same error for 'C' drive as well. And incidentally I have successfully installed few other software in 'C' as well as 'E' drive under folder 'Program Files'.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is self-evident and included in your question -- it's just not permitted to install SQL Server in an NTFS compressed location.

Now the interesting thing is, and I ran into this myself when I was using a small SSD, that after you install SQL Server you can go ahead and compress it or its parents with no issues, as well as take it into use with no issues whatsoever.

This limitation of the installer seems very arbitrary, as you would think the SQL Server's DB file repository would have this limitation, and not the location for the program files.

Answer (score 0):

Change folder for databases into some non-compressed or non-encrypted location. SQL server *databases* cannot reside on compressed or encrypted volume/folder (like error message almost tells you).

Comment: But the drive viz. E: is read write and I am able to use it normally. In fact, I created 'Program Files' folder manually in that drive. I also tried installing it in 'C' drive but same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: You may well be able to use them as normal for other operations, however SQL Server cannot. You need an uncompressed and unencrypted folder.

Comment: Read-write doesn't matter. Where does SQL installer suggest to put databases (under program files probably)? Have you your disk encrypted by chance? For normal file operations compressed or encrypted drives/folders can be used without limitations, but SQL server doesn't use normal file operations, it needs direct raw access to underlying media.

Comment: I tried installing it in 'C' drive also. But that too, failed.

Comment: So? C drive (or folders on it) can be both compressed or encrypted, you don't notice that. Explorer may display some folder names in blue however :) It is of course possible that some other driver issue interferes your setup, although I have not seen such behavior.